# Test if the required javascript files are evaluated/ready using casperjs

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, casperjs

I know I can use `waitForSelector` to test if a specific element is ready but what about javascript? For example if my page depends on a jquery plugin to work, the following code might fail if the js file didn't get loaded properly:

```
this.waitForSelector('#someid', function _then() {
    // do something that requires js to be fully loaded and functional
    // before clicking the submit button
    self.click('#submit')
}, function _timeout() {
    fail('Page timeout')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

What does your jquery plugin exactly do? based on that you can use

```
this.waitFor(function(){

      // return true based on your jquery plugin/ js code evaluation
      // eg: if your jquery sets a variable $x=10 by evaluating a particular jquery plugin code.
      return $x==10;

    }, function(){
       // what to do after the js code called

    }, function(){
       // when failed
});
```